# IntelliJ 2018.1 - Add Plug-in nature to project

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I cloned a project from GitHub, but IntelliJ doesn't see it as a Plug-in development project. Can I attach a Plug-in nature to it?

I'm using `IntelliJ 2018.1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete the old module in `Project Settings`, create a new `IntelliJ Platform Plugin` module and mark directories as sources, test, etc.

Comment: It worked! Thanks.
Anyway, the thing is the forked plugin is built using the intellij-gradle-plugin, so there is another workflow to follow.

Comment: Well then it is a different thing entirely, you have to execute gradle goals to do anything. No need for a special module type.